# Is there a way to get an image of the live view?

Tags: olympus, live-view

Is there any way for Olympus OM-D class cameras to store their own live view as an image?

---

For newcomers: the live view is what is displayed on the back of camera on the LCD screen when the camera is in view mode. Typically, it includes a subsampled version of the current scene the camera is registering with a configurable overlay of various settings, highlights/cues and camera state information:

[image: OM-D live view]

The image above is taken by a second camera (which is why there is a reflection on the image). I want to get a high-quality image of this display without having to use a second camera.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @mattdm To get a picture of the live view without using a second camera.

Comment: Why do you want a picture of the live view?

Comment: @mattdm, there are dozens of possible reasons. To what extent would this affect the answer?

Comment: Because this sounds like an xy problem. Maybe we can offer something that solves what you actually want to accomplish, but we can only do that if we actually know what it is.

Comment: Plus, "yes, press the shutter and that saves the image you see in the live view as JPEG and/or RAW" is a perfectly valid answer to this question as it is — but I bet not very satisfying to you. (Although, I guess, if that's what you really want, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.)

Comment: @mattdm Sorry, I didn't realize that some newcomers might not understand what the live view is. I have written a more detailed explanation and included it in the question.

Comment: It's not a matter of "newcomers". There are questions like "Do you want all the overlay stuff?" which would be clear if you'd simply state your end goal.

Comment: While I am not the author I would also like to get an image of live view to get all the data shown on it. Which spot was focused on and sometimes also how LV and final image differ in brightness, contrast and lens distortion. "Press the shutter" obviously produces nothing that is related to live view. (Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a solution for my ILCA77MK2.)

Comment: @Gerhardh If you think it is a useful question, why not upvote it?

Comment: It could be that someone wants to write documentation / guides that include the actual LV image, including the F-Stop, EV comp, etc, instead of taking the picture. 

Chances are there's an engineering mode that could do this, but then you'd need to find someone who knows the Olympus really well to find out.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm... There is the solution but it looks strange.

All OM-D cameras have HDMI output. So you have to connect your camera to TV or another device with HDMI input.
1. My TV does not allow to to take screenshots, but my friend's TV does.
2. Another way - not TV but any other device with HDMI input and video recording capabilities. Then you export any frame from video you like.